# An entity copy [] was already assigned to a different entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-roo

To be brief, I use User<->Role<->Right model in database and fetch rights of user on my UserDetails by the following code:

```
for (Role role : getRoles()) {
        for (Right right : role.getRights()) {
            Authority authority = new Authority( controller, action );
            authorites.add( authority );
        }
    }
```

When I try to update one of the right that is already loaded because of logged in user (fetched by the mentioned code), it raises **IllegalStateException** with *"assigned to a different entity message"*.

The Update is done by roo managed merge spect

```
@Transactional
public Right Right.merge() {
    if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
    Right merged = this.entityManager.merge(this);
    this.entityManager.flush();
    return merged;
}
```

The **put** method of **org.hibernate.event.internal.EventCache** that raises this is as:

```
if ( oldCopy == null ) {
        if  ( oldEntity != null ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Error occurred while storing entity " + printEntity( entity ) + ". An entity copy " + printEntity( copy )
                            + " was already assigned to a different entity " + printEntity( oldEntity ) + "."
            );
        }
        if ( oldOperatedOn != null ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "EventCache#entityToOperatedOnFlagMap contains an entity " + printEntity( entity )
                            + ", but EventCache#entityToCopyMap does not."
            );
        }
    }
```

roo can be instructed to generated general equal and hash, but I implemented equal and hash for **Right & Role** class as well, but nothing changed.

Stack:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:293)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:33)
com.cmon.model.Right_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.merge_aroundBody18(Right_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:72)
com.cmon.model.Right_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$AjcClosure19.run(Right_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:1)
org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
com.cmon.model.Right_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethod$com_cmon_model_Right_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$com_cmon_model_Right$merge(Right_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:70)
com.cmon.model.Right.merge(Right.java:1)
com.cmon.model.Right_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$com_cmon_model_Right_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$com_cmon_model_Right$merge(Right_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj)
com.cmon.controller.RightController_Roo_Controller.ajc$interMethod$com_cmon_controller_RightController_Roo_Controller$com_cmon_controller_RightController$update(RightController_Roo_Controller.aj:68)
com.cmon.controller.RightController.update(RightController.java:1)
com.cmon.controller.RightController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$835120d0.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:61)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
com.cmon.controller.RightController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3d91dbef.update(<generated>)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:849)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:74)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: can you post the stack please ?

Comment: what about equals() and hashcode() methods in all the object graph related to Right/Role ? (is SpringRoo generating proper implementations for those methods ?)

Comment: The point is that `EventCache` uses a `java.util.IdentityHashMap` to track merged entities. The map will never use the object's `equals()` method but rely on object identity. I've got the same problem with two objects from a converter (equal, but not identical). Still got to figure out how to fix this.